# IPython notebook shows output in terminal

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using an IPython notebook (`ipython notebook &`), but when I try to print something to get any output by simply giving the variable name ans pressing Shift + Enter, instead of getting the output in notebook (next to the cell), I get it in the terminal from where I launch the notebook. I want to see the output in the notebook itself, next to the concerned cell. I'm facing this problem lately, previously it was working fine.

Comment: I have noticed this bug before, resulting from loading particular modules (which presumably presumably play with the standard streams). I think it is a bug. (Make sure your IPython is up-to-date, though!)

Comment: What libraries have you imported? Does this always happen from the very beginning of every notebook? What version of IPython and Python, and what OS?

Comment: I'm importing `nltk`, `pickle`, `csv`, `pandas`, `xlrd`, `numpy`, `string`, `re`, `sys`, `collections` and `itertools`. Yes this happens for every print statement, right from the start of notebook. This is IPython version 1.1.0 and Python version 2.7.6. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Firefox 28.0.

Comment: Needs code to repro the issue.