# Print into console terminal not into cell output of IPython Notebook

Tags: python, windows, ipython, jupyter-notebook, python-3.4

I would like to print into the terminal window that runs IPython Notebook and not into the cell output. Printing into cell output consumes more memory and slows down my system when I issue a substantial number of `print` calls. In essence, I would like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306893/ipython-notebook-shows-output-in-terminal) behaviour by design.

I have tried the following:

1. I tried a different permutations of `print` and `sys.stdout.write` calls
2. I looked at the IPython Notebook documentation [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/notebook.html), [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%202%20-%20Basic%20Output.ipynb) and [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb) without help
3. I have tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494182/print-not-showing-in-ipython-notebook-python) as a workaround but it seems to be only working on Python 2.7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to redirect your output to the systems standard output device. This depends on your OS. On Mac that would be:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('/dev/stdout', 'w')
```

Type the above code in an IPython cell and evaluate it. Afterwards all output will show up in terminal.

Comment: Is there a way to reverse that ? and recover ipython stdout

Comment: You could e.g. safe a reference to notebook's `stdout` before redirecting: `nb_stdout = sys.stdout`. Now, you would redirect the output. To get back to in notebook output simply write: `sys.stdout = nb_stdout`. A cleaner solution would be to use [contextlib.redirect_stdout(new_target)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) context manager.

Comment: @MaxPowers Do you know what you should write in Windows?

Comment: @MaxPowers: Note that `contextlib.redirect_stdout` only works in python 3.4 and above.

Comment: Thanks to you, I can `sys.stderr = open('/dev/stderr', 'w')`; but how do I make this available for Windows?

Comment: @MaxPowers In my case, I am running subprocess and the output is sent to the terminal, but not to the notebook. Any ideas?

Comment: On windows you can do `sys.stderr = open('con', 'w')`

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, this can work:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(1, 'w')
```

Comment: Hey you are copied answer of @MaxPowers and posting

Comment: What about `sys.stderr`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to switch form one to the other easily:

```py
terminal_output = open('/dev/stdout', 'w')

print('this will show up in the IPython cell output')
print('this will show up in the terminal', file=terminal_output)
```

Similarly, `terminal_error = open('/dev/stderr', 'w')` can be used to send to the terminal stderr, without any conflict with the default behavior of `sys.stderr` (which is to print an error message in the IPython cell output).